# Taking user input + checking value

Tags: java, int, double, java.util.scanner

Suppose I get a user input via

```
input.nextDouble()
```

if the input is 455 and I store it as a double, will java take this value and turn it into 455.00? Or will it throw an exception?

If so, does it throw on the nextDouble? or the storage via double datatype?

Comment: It doesn't "turn it into" anything.  `455` and `455.00` have the same internal representation, if you're using `double`.

Comment: cool, thanks @DavidWallace Feel free to submit an answer and I'll accept it when I can.

Answer (score 0):

`nextDouble()` will happily accept the int value and store it as `double`. but be careful if you are calling it in conjunction with another `nextXXX()` method like :

```
 int i=0;
 double d = 0;
    while(scanner.hasNext()){

       if(scanner.hasNextDouble()){
         d= scanner.nextDouble();
     }else{
         i= scanner.nextInt();
     }    
  }
```

`else` here won't execute since `hasNextDouble()` will return true for `int` values and `nextDouble()` will take them and save them in `d`.